# Can "$\omega_1$-Barwise-ness" be ensured by a first-order theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, computability

With the [Barwise compactness theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0049237X0870689X) in mind, say that a countable infinite ordinal $\alpha$ is **$\omega_1$-Barwise** iff whenever $T$ is a $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$ set of $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\color{red}{\omega_1}}$-sentences and every  subtheory of $T$ which is an element of $L_\alpha$ is satisfiable, then $T$ itself is satisfiable. Such ordinals [do in fact exist](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400575/which-countable-ordinals-are-barwise-compact-for-mathcall-infty-omega-1) by an elementary argument which in fact applies to pretty much any "$\mathsf{HC}$-coded" logic.

I'm broadly curious about the $\omega_1$-Barwise ordinals. At the above-linked question I asked how large they must be; here I'd like to ask a somewhat different question, namely whether $\omega_1$-Barwiseness can be approximated in a *finitary first-order* way:

> Is there a first-order theory $\mathsf{B}$ in the language of set theory such that $(i)$ uncountably many countable levels of $L$ satisfy $\mathsf{B}$ and $(ii)$ whenever $\alpha$ is countable and $L_\alpha\models \mathsf{B}$ we have that $\alpha$ is $\omega_1$-Barwise?

Recall that Barwise showed that exactly this happens at $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$: if $L_\alpha\models\mathsf{KP}$ then we get the usual Barwise compactness property at $L_\alpha$. So this isn't *completely* ludicrous (although I am highly confident that the answer is negative).

Comment: Are you assuming $V=L$?

Comment: @FarmerS Ideally not, but I would be willing to if necessary. (And I think it is plausibly necessary here, to be fair.)

Comment: Okay, there is no such $B\in L$. (Otherwise you can have a theory $T$ identify a specific level $A$ of $L$ which models $B$, but put too many ordinals in it for it to be actually realized by $A$. But this depends on having $B$ as a parameter to define $T$.) It would be interesting to know what happens more generally.

Comment: Does your argument for existence assume $V=L$? Otherwise how do you get that closure point?

Comment: @FarmerS Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how this uses $V=L$. It's fine if $\omega_1\not=\omega_1^L$ for example, "$\omega_1$" throughout here refers to $\omega_1^V$.

Comment: Separately, I don't follow your earlier comment that there is no $B\in L$; can you elaborate?

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, I was confused about something in the existence argument, but I understand now.

Comment: No such $B\in L$: Otherwise let $\alpha$ be least such that $B\in L_\alpha$ and $L_\alpha\models B$ (note since $B$ is in a finite language, it is constructed before $\omega_1^L$, and $\alpha<\omega_1^L$). For simplicity I will assume $\alpha=\mathrm{Ord}\cap L_\alpha$. Consider the theory $T$ with constants $\beta$ for each $\beta<\alpha$, plus a constant $\alpha’$, and some more constants, asserting…

Comment: …all statements in $B$ + „I am a (wellfounded) level of $L$ and have no proper segment which models $B$ and contains $B$ as an element“ + the statements „$\gamma<\beta<\alpha’  \in \mathrm{Ord}$” for each $\gamma<\beta<\alpha$. We use the extra constants to refer to $B$ and add statements describing it. Note that each fragment of $T$ which is in $L_\alpha$ is modelled by $L_\alpha$, but $ T$ itself is not satisfiable.   And $T$ is $\Sigma_1^{L_\alpha}(\{B\})$.

Comment: And there can’t be a stationary-in-$L$ set of $\alpha<\omega_1^L$ such that $L_\alpha\models B$, because there is an $L$-club $C$ such that $L_\alpha\models T$, the theory of $L_{\omega_1^L}$, so we would get $B\subseteq T\in  L$, so we now get a contradiction as before using $T$ instead of $B$.

Comment: @FarmerS Sorry for the late reply. That's nice - even though it doesn't fully answer the question, if you put it as an answer I'll upvote it (and award it the bounty if a fuller answer doesn't come along).